# What kind of key would I use for this StoreBuilder

Tags: android, kotlin, repository, dropbox, store

So I'm trying out Store 4 (https://github.com/dropbox/Store) with a simple android app that fetches data form this placeholder site: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

The first screen would be a list of all the users. I want to fetch them the first time you open the app. But when you reopen the app or get back to the first screen I want fetch it from the room database first and then fetch them from the internet (the fact that the database is not changing is trivial).

I expect my ViewModel would need to accept the object created by the StoreBuilder, so I'm creating the definition of this object in my DI (Koin). StoreBuilder keeps asking me to provide a Key though. And I'm beginning to suspect that Store is not the right choice if you're fetching **all** the users. I'm trying to use Store in my program because I'm interested in using it. My question is, how? Or simply put:

> What is the key that I should use in this case? Should I use a key at all? Why do I need to use a key?

Small excerpt of my code so far (not that it builds):

```
object KoinModules {
    val repositoryModule = module {
        single { StoreBuilder
            .fromNonFlow { provideUserService(get()).getAll() //** THIS IS NOT WORKING **
            }.persister(
                reader = provideUserDAO(get())::getAll,
                writer = provideUserDAO(get())::insert
            )
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM UserDTO")
    suspend fun getAll(): List<UserDto>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(vararg userDTO: UserDto)
}
```

```
interface UserService {
    @GET("/users")
    suspend fun getAll(): List<User>
}
```

```
@Parcelize
data class User(val id: Int, val name: String, val username: String, val email: String) : Parcelable
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the key describes:

> Store uses generic keys as identifiers for data. A key can be any value object that properly implements toString(), equals() and hashCode(). When your Fetcher function is called, it will be passed a particular Key value. Similarly, the key will be used as a primary identifier within caches (Make sure to have a proper hashCode()!!).

the key is to define your data, the object which you use as key have to override the `hashCode` method, define your own rule.

here is some use in Store:

> suspend fun Store.get(key: Key): Value: This method returns a single value for the given key. If available, it will be returned from the in memory cache or the persister

it is according to your set key to return the data. its functions as the key in `hashmap`

Comment: Ok, so should I just generate a random integer everytime I try to fetch all users? It seems like I'm obligated to fetch my users with a specific variable (like by ID), but in this case I want to fetch all users, from a specific address

Comment: I suggest you use unique and fixed data as the key, not a random integer. all user key can like this "all+usertype-function"

Comment: Which means I would have an insert function in my dao which also should accept a string that would always contain an arbitrary string like "all+usertype-function"? That sounds like bad code. Would this be something where I could open an issue for?

Comment: `A key can be any value object that properly implements toString()`, I only show example info for id, for the database, it often uses rawid as the unique key